# sum the list of dictionary if there are the same key using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
customer1 = {'name': 'John Smith',"qty": 10, 'income': 35, 'email': 'john.smith1@email.com'}
customer2 = {'name': 'John Smith', "qty": 10,'income': 28, 'phone': '555-555-5555',"other": "something", 'email': 'john.smith@email.com'}
customer3 = {'name': 'Bob Johnson',"qty": 10,'income': 20, 'address': '123 Main St', 'email': 'bob.johnson@email.com',"c2":"abc","c3":"edf"}
customer3 = {'name': 'Joe Johnson', "qty": 10,'income': 8, 'address': '123 Main St', 'email': 'bob.johnson@email.com',"c2":"abc","c3":"edf"}

data = [customer1, customer2, customer3]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

I want to sum it `qty` and `income` if there is the same name, the result will look like

```
result = [
     {'name': 'John Smith', "qty": 20,'income': 63, 'phone': '555-555-5555',"other": "something", 'email': 'john.smith@email.com','email2': 'john.smith1@email.com'},
     {'name': 'Bob Johnson',"qty": 10,'income': 20, 'address': '123 Main St', 'email': 'bob.johnson@email.com',"c2":"kanel","c3":"pong"},
     {'name': 'Joe Johnson', "qty": 10,'income': 8, 'address': '123 Main St', 'email': 'bob.johnson@email.com',"c2":"abc","c3":"edf"}
```

]

Comment: `df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg({'qty': 'sum', 'income': 'sum'}|dict.fromkeys(['email', 'phone', 'other', 'address', 'c2', 'c3'], 'first'))`

Comment: more details please

Comment: What is unclear? Have you checked the duplicates?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: OK, you have python < 3.9. You can use a dictionary comprehension like in the second duplicate. But I'll give more details

Comment: I saw that you also want to pivot the emails, so I provided a complete answer. And a workaround for python < 3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to aggregate as sum for qty/income, then use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` as method, and for all other columns `first`.

```
funcs = ({'qty': 'sum', 'income': 'sum'}
        |dict.fromkeys(['email', 'phone', 'other', 'address', 'c2', 'c3'], 'first')
        )
out = df.groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(funcs)
```

For python < 3.9, you can use:

```
funcs = {'qty': 'sum', 'income': 'sum'}
funcs = {**funcs, **dict.fromkeys(['email', 'phone', 'other', 'address', 'c2', 'c3'], 'first')}
```

Output:

```
          name  qty  income                  email         phone      other      address     c2    c3
0   John Smith   20      63  john.smith1@email.com  555-555-5555  something         None   None  None
1  Bob Johnson   10      20  bob.johnson@email.com          None       None  123 Main St  kanel  pong
2  Joe Johnson   10       8  bob.johnson@email.com          None       None  123 Main St  kanel  pong
```

#### emails as new columns

If you also want new columns for the email as shown in your output, then you can aggregate those as list, convert to [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) seperately, and then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the output:

```
funcs = ({'qty': 'sum', 'income': 'sum', 'email': list}
        |dict.fromkeys(['phone', 'other', 'address', 'c2', 'c3'], 'first')
        )
out = df.groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(funcs)
out = out.join(pd.DataFrame(out.pop('email').tolist()).rename(columns=lambda x: f'email_{x+1}'))
```

Output:

```
          name  qty  income         phone      other      address     c2    c3                email_1               email_2
0   John Smith   20      63  555-555-5555  something         None   None  None  john.smith1@email.com  john.smith@email.com
1  Bob Johnson   10      20          None       None  123 Main St  kanel  pong  bob.johnson@email.com                  None
2  Joe Johnson   10       8          None       None  123 Main St  kanel  pong  bob.johnson@email.com                  None
```